# Subclassing SimpleCursorAdapter to include convertView for memory conservation

Tags: android, list, android-listview, recycle

I've been scouring throug the examples and tutorials but I can't seem to get my head around how to handle recycling within a subclassed SimpleCursorAdapter.  I know that for regular ArrayAdapters you can check convertView for null and inflate if null from the xml and if not null, recycle, but I'm having a little trouble visualizing how that works with the from and to arrays within the SimpleCursorAdapter subclass.  I tried to figure this out from the The Busy Coders Guide to Android Development by Commonsware but was unsuccessful.  If anyone knows of any tips, examples, or tutorials, I would be grateful to see them.

Comment: While this is old, for those looking at it in the future: The code for SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't override getView; instead, it overrides at bindView, after getView -- in CursorAdapter -- checks for the convertView. (Code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was unable to find any good examples for Subclassing the SimpleCursorAdapter to use the convertView recycle methodolgy so I ended up subclassing CursorAdapter instead.  This actually worked quite well for my implementation and is blazing fast with a dramatic decrease in memory usage.  Recycling views really works and I recommend it highly!

Here is an example of my implementation:

```
 private static class MyNiftyAdapter extends CursorAdapter
    {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Cursor cur;

        public MyNiftyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context,c);       
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.cur = c;
        }
        public MyNiftyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery)
        {
            super(context, c, autoRequery);
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.cur = c;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chamber_item, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
                viewHolder.city = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.city);
                viewHolder.state = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.state);
                viewHolder.country = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.country);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else
            {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            this.cur.moveToPosition(position);

            viewHolder.name.setText(this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.NAME)));          
            viewHolder.city.setText(this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.CITY)));
            viewHolder.state.setText(this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.STATE)));
            viewHolder.country.setText(this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.COUNTRY)));            

            return convertView;
        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#bindView(android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)
         */
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            // Dont need to do anything here

        }
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#newView(android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor, android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Dont need to do anything here either
            return null;
        }

        static class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView name;
            TextView city;
            TextView state;
            TextView country;
        }
    }
```

Each row in my list now displays name, city, state, and country exactly as I wanted.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this still needed with the new `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor?  I am curious because I thought that it wasn't, but the performance of my `ListView` is horrendous.

Comment: I think what you did is not the right way. Instead of overriding `getView()` which is not an abstract method, you could simply override `newView()` and `bindView()` functions to create a new view or use a previously created view. CursorAdapter will take care of creating a new view or recycling a previously created one when necessary. Less code, cleaner, and actually the standrad way!

Answer (score 5):

CursorAdapter does the work partially for you. You only need to override newView() when a new view needs to be created, and bindView() when an existing view is recycled.

Comment: Would you know where I could see an example?

Answer (score 3):

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccountsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
 public static final String TAG = AccountsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

 private Boolean DEBUG=true;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;
 private int layoutResource;
 private Cursor mCursor;
 private int acctInd;
 private int upicInd;
 private  ViewHolder holder;
 public AccountsAdapter(Context context,Cursor c,int resourceId) {
     super(context,c);
     this.mCursor=c;
     acctInd=mCursor.getColumnIndex(LJDB.KEY_JOURNALNAME);
     upicInd=mCursor.getColumnIndex(LJDB.KEY_DEFAULTUSERPIC);

     this.layoutResource=resourceId;
     this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }


 private static class ViewHolder {
     ImageView userpic;
     TextView journalname;
 }
```

@Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
       holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.journalname.setText(cursor.getString(acctInd));
            holder.userpic.setTag(cursor.getString(upicInd));

}
  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = mInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
             holder.userpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.duserpic);
             holder.journalname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.uname);

v.setTag(holder);
         return v;

}
}

Answer (score 1):

You could also subclass [ResourceCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ResourceCursorAdapter.html). In that case you only need to override the bindview method:

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, R.layout.myLayout, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if (viewHolder == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    viewHolder.bind(cursor, context);
}

/**
 * A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
 * to findViewById() on each row (especially during scrolling)
 */
private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView text;

    private ToggleButton toggle;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        toggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rowToggleButton);
    }

    /**
     * Bind the data from the cursor to the proper views that are hold in
     * this holder
     * @param cursor
     */
    public void bind(Cursor cursor, Context context) {
        toggle.setChecked(0 != cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ENABLED")));
        text.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TEXT")));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing, it appears that the accepted answer is incorrect (more so, unnecessary).

From what I can tell (based on a simple Log.e output test), view recycling is correctly handled by default (as @Romain Guy stated). Which I think would justify there being no recommendation for you to need to override **getView()** in any documentation I have come across.

This was the code snippet used in the simple example I used to come to this conclusion:

```
public class MediaAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void bindView(View arg0, Context arg1, Cursor arg2) {
        Log.e("bindView", "Called: " + arg2.getPosition());
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) arg0;
        iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(arg1.getContentResolver(), 
                arg2.getInt(arg2.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null)));

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        Log.e("newView", "Called: " + arg1.getPosition());
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctFrag);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 96));
        iv.setPadding(Spine.getDp(2), Spine.getDp(2), Spine.getDp(2), Spine.getDp(2));

        return iv;
    }

}
```

When using this in a GridView to display a grid of Image thumbnails available the LogCat output was the following:

```
06-11 21:50:09.906: E/newView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:09.906: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:09.929: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:09.937: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:09.945: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:09.953: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:09.968: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:09.984: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.000: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 555K, 5% free 14670K/15303K, paused 1ms+6ms
06-11 21:50:10.023: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.031: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.047: E/newView(3192): Called: 1
06-11 21:50:10.047: E/bindView(3192): Called: 1
06-11 21:50:10.062: E/newView(3192): Called: 2
06-11 21:50:10.062: E/bindView(3192): Called: 2
06-11 21:50:10.070: E/newView(3192): Called: 3
06-11 21:50:10.070: E/bindView(3192): Called: 3
06-11 21:50:10.078: E/newView(3192): Called: 4
06-11 21:50:10.078: E/bindView(3192): Called: 4
06-11 21:50:10.086: E/newView(3192): Called: 5
06-11 21:50:10.086: E/bindView(3192): Called: 5
06-11 21:50:10.093: E/newView(3192): Called: 6
06-11 21:50:10.093: E/bindView(3192): Called: 6
06-11 21:50:10.093: E/newView(3192): Called: 7
06-11 21:50:10.093: E/bindView(3192): Called: 7
06-11 21:50:10.101: E/newView(3192): Called: 8
06-11 21:50:10.101: E/bindView(3192): Called: 8
06-11 21:50:10.101: E/newView(3192): Called: 9
06-11 21:50:10.101: E/bindView(3192): Called: 9
06-11 21:50:10.125: E/newView(3192): Called: 10
06-11 21:50:10.125: E/bindView(3192): Called: 10
06-11 21:50:10.133: E/newView(3192): Called: 11
06-11 21:50:10.133: E/bindView(3192): Called: 11
06-11 21:50:10.140: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 351K, 3% free 15001K/15431K, paused 1ms+2ms
06-11 21:50:10.140: E/newView(3192): Called: 12
06-11 21:50:10.140: E/bindView(3192): Called: 12
06-11 21:50:10.164: E/newView(3192): Called: 13
06-11 21:50:10.164: E/bindView(3192): Called: 13
06-11 21:50:10.179: E/newView(3192): Called: 14
06-11 21:50:10.179: E/bindView(3192): Called: 14
06-11 21:50:10.187: E/newView(3192): Called: 15
06-11 21:50:10.187: E/bindView(3192): Called: 15
06-11 21:50:10.195: E/newView(3192): Called: 16
06-11 21:50:10.195: E/bindView(3192): Called: 16
06-11 21:50:10.203: E/newView(3192): Called: 17
06-11 21:50:10.203: E/bindView(3192): Called: 17
06-11 21:50:10.211: E/newView(3192): Called: 18
06-11 21:50:10.211: E/bindView(3192): Called: 18
06-11 21:50:10.218: E/newView(3192): Called: 19
06-11 21:50:10.218: E/bindView(3192): Called: 19
06-11 21:50:10.218: E/newView(3192): Called: 20
06-11 21:50:10.218: E/bindView(3192): Called: 20
06-11 21:50:10.218: E/newView(3192): Called: 21
06-11 21:50:10.218: E/bindView(3192): Called: 21
06-11 21:50:10.226: E/newView(3192): Called: 22
06-11 21:50:10.226: E/bindView(3192): Called: 22
06-11 21:50:10.226: E/newView(3192): Called: 23
06-11 21:50:10.226: E/bindView(3192): Called: 23
06-11 21:50:10.234: E/newView(3192): Called: 24
06-11 21:50:10.234: E/bindView(3192): Called: 24
06-11 21:50:10.234: E/newView(3192): Called: 25
06-11 21:50:10.234: E/bindView(3192): Called: 25
06-11 21:50:10.242: E/newView(3192): Called: 26
06-11 21:50:10.242: E/bindView(3192): Called: 26
06-11 21:50:10.242: E/newView(3192): Called: 27
06-11 21:50:10.242: E/bindView(3192): Called: 27
06-11 21:50:10.250: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 2% free 15582K/15879K, paused 1ms+1ms
06-11 21:50:10.250: E/newView(3192): Called: 28
06-11 21:50:10.250: E/bindView(3192): Called: 28
06-11 21:50:10.265: E/newView(3192): Called: 29
06-11 21:50:10.265: E/bindView(3192): Called: 29
06-11 21:50:10.265: E/newView(3192): Called: 30
06-11 21:50:10.265: E/bindView(3192): Called: 30
06-11 21:50:10.273: E/newView(3192): Called: 31
06-11 21:50:10.273: E/bindView(3192): Called: 31
06-11 21:50:10.273: E/newView(3192): Called: 32
06-11 21:50:10.273: E/bindView(3192): Called: 32
06-11 21:50:10.281: E/newView(3192): Called: 33
06-11 21:50:10.281: E/bindView(3192): Called: 33
06-11 21:50:10.281: E/newView(3192): Called: 34
06-11 21:50:10.281: E/bindView(3192): Called: 34
06-11 21:50:10.289: E/newView(3192): Called: 35
06-11 21:50:10.289: E/bindView(3192): Called: 35
06-11 21:50:10.289: E/newView(3192): Called: 36
06-11 21:50:10.289: E/bindView(3192): Called: 36
06-11 21:50:10.297: E/newView(3192): Called: 37
06-11 21:50:10.297: E/bindView(3192): Called: 37
06-11 21:50:10.297: E/newView(3192): Called: 38
06-11 21:50:10.297: E/bindView(3192): Called: 38
06-11 21:50:10.297: E/newView(3192): Called: 39
06-11 21:50:10.297: E/bindView(3192): Called: 39
06-11 21:50:10.304: E/newView(3192): Called: 40
06-11 21:50:10.304: E/bindView(3192): Called: 40
06-11 21:50:10.304: E/newView(3192): Called: 41
06-11 21:50:10.304: E/bindView(3192): Called: 41
06-11 21:50:10.312: E/newView(3192): Called: 42
06-11 21:50:10.312: E/bindView(3192): Called: 42
06-11 21:50:10.312: E/newView(3192): Called: 43
06-11 21:50:10.312: E/bindView(3192): Called: 43
06-11 21:50:10.320: E/newView(3192): Called: 44
06-11 21:50:10.320: E/bindView(3192): Called: 44
06-11 21:50:10.336: E/newView(3192): Called: 45
06-11 21:50:10.336: E/bindView(3192): Called: 45
06-11 21:50:10.343: E/newView(3192): Called: 46
06-11 21:50:10.343: E/bindView(3192): Called: 46
06-11 21:50:10.351: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 3% free 16297K/16647K, paused 1ms+3ms
06-11 21:50:10.351: E/newView(3192): Called: 47
06-11 21:50:10.351: E/bindView(3192): Called: 47
06-11 21:50:10.351: E/newView(3192): Called: 48
06-11 21:50:10.359: E/bindView(3192): Called: 48
06-11 21:50:10.367: E/newView(3192): Called: 49
06-11 21:50:10.367: E/bindView(3192): Called: 49
06-11 21:50:10.383: E/newView(3192): Called: 50
06-11 21:50:10.383: E/bindView(3192): Called: 50
06-11 21:50:10.390: E/newView(3192): Called: 51
06-11 21:50:10.390: E/bindView(3192): Called: 51
06-11 21:50:10.406: E/newView(3192): Called: 52
06-11 21:50:10.406: E/bindView(3192): Called: 52
06-11 21:50:10.414: E/newView(3192): Called: 53
06-11 21:50:10.414: E/bindView(3192): Called: 53
06-11 21:50:10.422: E/newView(3192): Called: 54
06-11 21:50:10.422: E/bindView(3192): Called: 54
06-11 21:50:10.422: E/newView(3192): Called: 55
06-11 21:50:10.422: E/bindView(3192): Called: 55
06-11 21:50:10.429: E/newView(3192): Called: 56
06-11 21:50:10.429: E/bindView(3192): Called: 56
06-11 21:50:10.437: E/newView(3192): Called: 57
06-11 21:50:10.437: E/bindView(3192): Called: 57
06-11 21:50:10.453: E/newView(3192): Called: 58
06-11 21:50:10.453: E/bindView(3192): Called: 58
06-11 21:50:10.461: E/newView(3192): Called: 59
06-11 21:50:10.461: E/bindView(3192): Called: 59
06-11 21:50:10.468: E/newView(3192): Called: 60
06-11 21:50:10.468: E/bindView(3192): Called: 60
06-11 21:50:10.484: E/newView(3192): Called: 61
06-11 21:50:10.484: E/bindView(3192): Called: 61
06-11 21:50:10.492: E/newView(3192): Called: 62
06-11 21:50:10.492: E/bindView(3192): Called: 62
06-11 21:50:10.508: E/newView(3192): Called: 63
06-11 21:50:10.508: E/bindView(3192): Called: 63
06-11 21:50:10.515: E/newView(3192): Called: 64
06-11 21:50:10.515: E/bindView(3192): Called: 64
06-11 21:50:10.523: E/newView(3192): Called: 65
06-11 21:50:10.523: E/bindView(3192): Called: 65
06-11 21:50:10.539: E/newView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.539: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.547: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.547: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.578: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.593: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 392K, 3% free 17115K/17543K, paused 2ms+7ms
06-11 21:50:10.601: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.609: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.625: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:10.633: E/bindView(3192): Called: 0
06-11 21:50:14.586: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 307K, 4% free 18033K/18695K, paused 14ms
06-11 21:50:14.632: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 19439K/19911K, paused 11ms
06-11 21:50:14.632: E/bindView(3192): Called: 66
06-11 21:50:14.640: E/bindView(3192): Called: 67
06-11 21:50:14.640: E/bindView(3192): Called: 68
06-11 21:50:14.648: E/bindView(3192): Called: 69
06-11 21:50:14.648: E/bindView(3192): Called: 70
06-11 21:50:14.656: E/bindView(3192): Called: 71
06-11 21:50:14.656: E/bindView(3192): Called: 72
06-11 21:50:14.664: E/bindView(3192): Called: 73
06-11 21:50:14.664: E/bindView(3192): Called: 74
06-11 21:50:14.672: E/bindView(3192): Called: 75
06-11 21:50:14.672: E/bindView(3192): Called: 76
06-11 21:50:14.679: E/bindView(3192): Called: 77
06-11 21:50:14.679: E/bindView(3192): Called: 78
06-11 21:50:14.687: E/newView(3192): Called: 79
06-11 21:50:14.687: E/bindView(3192): Called: 79
06-11 21:50:14.687: E/newView(3192): Called: 80
06-11 21:50:14.687: E/bindView(3192): Called: 80
06-11 21:50:14.687: E/newView(3192): Called: 81
06-11 21:50:14.687: E/bindView(3192): Called: 81
06-11 21:50:14.695: E/newView(3192): Called: 82
06-11 21:50:14.695: E/bindView(3192): Called: 82
06-11 21:50:14.695: E/newView(3192): Called: 83
06-11 21:50:14.695: E/bindView(3192): Called: 83
06-11 21:50:14.750: E/bindView(3192): Called: 84
06-11 21:50:14.750: E/bindView(3192): Called: 85
06-11 21:50:14.757: E/bindView(3192): Called: 86
06-11 21:50:14.757: E/bindView(3192): Called: 87
06-11 21:50:14.765: E/bindView(3192): Called: 88
06-11 21:50:14.765: E/bindView(3192): Called: 89
06-11 21:50:14.812: E/bindView(3192): Called: 90
06-11 21:50:14.820: E/bindView(3192): Called: 91
06-11 21:50:14.820: E/bindView(3192): Called: 92
06-11 21:50:14.828: E/bindView(3192): Called: 93
06-11 21:50:14.828: E/bindView(3192): Called: 94
06-11 21:50:14.828: E/bindView(3192): Called: 95
06-11 21:50:14.851: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1350K, 7% free 20078K/21511K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-11 21:50:14.882: E/bindView(3192): Called: 96
06-11 21:50:14.890: E/bindView(3192): Called: 97
06-11 21:50:14.890: E/bindView(3192): Called: 98
06-11 21:50:14.890: E/bindView(3192): Called: 99
06-11 21:50:14.898: E/bindView(3192): Called: 100
06-11 21:50:14.898: E/bindView(3192): Called: 101
06-11 21:50:14.945: E/bindView(3192): Called: 102
06-11 21:50:14.945: E/bindView(3192): Called: 103
06-11 21:50:14.953: E/bindView(3192): Called: 104
06-11 21:50:14.953: E/bindView(3192): Called: 105
06-11 21:50:14.961: E/bindView(3192): Called: 106
06-11 21:50:14.961: E/bindView(3192): Called: 107
06-11 21:50:15.078: E/bindView(3192): Called: 108
06-11 21:50:15.086: E/bindView(3192): Called: 109
06-11 21:50:15.086: E/bindView(3192): Called: 110
06-11 21:50:15.093: E/bindView(3192): Called: 111
06-11 21:50:15.093: E/bindView(3192): Called: 112
06-11 21:50:15.101: E/bindView(3192): Called: 113
06-11 21:50:15.711: E/bindView(3192): Called: 114
06-11 21:50:15.718: E/bindView(3192): Called: 115
06-11 21:50:15.718: E/bindView(3192): Called: 116
06-11 21:50:15.726: E/bindView(3192): Called: 117
06-11 21:50:15.726: E/bindView(3192): Called: 118
06-11 21:50:15.734: E/bindView(3192): Called: 119
06-11 21:50:15.734: E/bindView(3192): Called: 120
06-11 21:50:15.742: E/bindView(3192): Called: 121
06-11 21:50:15.742: E/bindView(3192): Called: 122
06-11 21:50:15.750: E/bindView(3192): Called: 123
06-11 21:50:15.750: E/bindView(3192): Called: 124
06-11 21:50:15.757: E/bindView(3192): Called: 125
06-11 21:50:15.867: E/bindView(3192): Called: 126
06-11 21:50:15.867: E/bindView(3192): Called: 127
06-11 21:50:15.875: E/bindView(3192): Called: 128
06-11 21:50:15.875: E/bindView(3192): Called: 129
06-11 21:50:15.882: E/bindView(3192): Called: 130
06-11 21:50:15.882: E/bindView(3192): Called: 131
06-11 21:50:15.922: E/bindView(3192): Called: 132
06-11 21:50:15.929: E/bindView(3192): Called: 133
06-11 21:50:15.929: E/bindView(3192): Called: 134
06-11 21:50:15.953: E/bindView(3192): Called: 135
06-11 21:50:15.961: E/bindView(3192): Called: 136
06-11 21:50:15.961: E/bindView(3192): Called: 137
06-11 21:50:15.968: D/dalvikvm(3192): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2012K, 10% free 20197K/22215K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-11 21:50:15.968: E/bindView(3192): Called: 138
06-11 21:50:15.976: E/bindView(3192): Called: 139
06-11 21:50:15.984: E/bindView(3192): Called: 140
06-11 21:50:15.984: E/bindView(3192): Called: 141
06-11 21:50:15.992: E/bindView(3192): Called: 142
06-11 21:50:15.992: E/bindView(3192): Called: 143
06-11 21:50:16.039: E/bindView(3192): Called: 144
06-11 21:50:16.039: E/bindView(3192): Called: 145
06-11 21:50:16.047: E/bindView(3192): Called: 146
06-11 21:50:16.047: E/bindView(3192): Called: 147
06-11 21:50:16.054: E/bindView(3192): Called: 148
06-11 21:50:16.054: E/bindView(3192): Called: 149
06-11 21:50:16.062: E/bindView(3192): Called: 150
06-11 21:50:16.062: E/bindView(3192): Called: 151
06-11 21:50:16.062: E/bindView(3192): Called: 152
06-11 21:50:16.070: E/bindView(3192): Called: 153
06-11 21:50:16.070: E/bindView(3192): Called: 154
06-11 21:50:16.070: E/bindView(3192): Called: 155
06-11 21:50:16.117: E/bindView(3192): Called: 156
06-11 21:50:16.117: E/bindView(3192): Called: 157
06-11 21:50:16.125: E/bindView(3192): Called: 158
06-11 21:50:16.125: E/bindView(3192): Called: 159
06-11 21:50:16.125: E/bindView(3192): Called: 160
06-11 21:50:16.132: E/bindView(3192): Called: 161
06-11 21:50:16.172: E/bindView(3192): Called: 162
06-11 21:50:16.172: E/bindView(3192): Called: 163
06-11 21:50:16.179: E/bindView(3192): Called: 164
06-11 21:50:16.179: E/bindView(3192): Called: 165
06-11 21:50:16.187: E/bindView(3192): Called: 166
06-11 21:50:16.187: E/bindView(3192): Called: 167
06-11 21:50:16.328: E/bindView(3192): Called: 168
06-11 21:50:16.336: E/bindView(3192): Called: 169
06-11 21:50:16.336: E/bindView(3192): Called: 170
06-11 21:50:16.343: E/bindView(3192): Called: 171
06-11 21:50:16.343: E/bindView(3192): Called: 172
06-11 21:50:16.351: E/bindView(3192): Called: 173
06-11 21:50:16.461: E/bindView(3192): Called: 174
06-11 21:50:16.468: E/bindView(3192): Called: 175
06-11 21:50:16.492: E/bindView(3192): Called: 176
06-11 21:50:16.492: E/bindView(3192): Called: 177
```

This seems to show quite clearly that once the views have been created by a call to **newView()**, **bindView()** handles converting the views to optimize memory.

(The few lines where **newView()** is called around the middle are just the **GridView** requiring a new row when displaying two fractions of a row as opposed to one whole).

Comment: I'm using just a SimpleCursorAdapter and not overriding anything. My views are just TextViews. I did see Romain Guy's listview video and he says there's a bad way to override getView, but I'm not overriding it, so is it bad not to override it?

Comment: No, it is never bad not to override something that has already been written. This issue here is more talking about overriding something with a consequence of overriding the already implemented memory optimization methods. It is never bad (realise that sweeping statement may be met with an exception....) to override something that is already written. Overriding is generally done to extend functionality if what is already there doesn't do what you require.

Comment: @flobacca Could you please post the link to that video?

Comment: @Lai Vung Oops, well I'm pretty sure I was talking about Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70  However, the part I'm listening to says there's a slow way, medium way and fast way. I guess there's no "bad" way, but slow can be though of as bad.

Comment: @flobacca Thank you. I knew that video. Unfortunately I couldn't find the moment when they talked about CursorAdapter (or SimpleCursorAdapter...). I think they talked about "view holder" approach. Or I think I misunderstood your first comment...

Comment: @Lai Vung : slow way is talked about at 8:40/59:43. Well, looks like you saw the video already though.