# Binding ViewHolder to get data from my cursor and display it

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

Guys I'm a self taught android developer, pretty new but I'm trying hard.
I've been looking a lot for some help with adapters and ViewHolder. I find it very hard to understand how to use the ViewHolder pattern to cache my widgets and then display them.

Basically I have a cursor that reads data from my SQLite DB. I've used SimpleCursorAdapter to display the results to the listview and it worked fine. Only problem was scrolling was very slow.

Now I'm trying to implement the ViewHolder pattern but cant figure out how to bind the data from my DB to the ViewHolder and then, display it.

Please, please help me! I've been looking for the answer for 2 months!

The code (I've left unrelevant code outside to make it simpler):

```
    public class Shifts extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener,
    SimpleGestureListener {


private Typeface tf = Entry.tf, tf2 = Entry.tf2, roboto = Entry.roboto;
public static int count = 1;
int dbHourTime = 0;
private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
public static DBAdapter DB;
public static Cursor cursor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.shifts);

    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);

    DB = new DBAdapter(this);
    DB.open();
    cursor = DB.getAllShifts();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    count = cursor.getPosition();
    int g = count;

    cursor.moveToNext();

    String[] columns = new String[] { DB.KEY_DATE, DB.KEY_HOURS,
            DB.KEY_DAY, DB.KEY_ROWID, DB.KEY_START, DB.KEY_END };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.dateDisp, R.id.shiftDisp, R.id.day,
            R.id.rawId, R.id.start, R.id.finish };

    TextView SF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    SF.setTypeface(tf);

    TextView sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sum);
    sum.setTypeface(tf);

    TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    empty.setTypeface(roboto);

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_entry, cursor, columns, to);
    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

The Code for the adapter:

```
private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap layoutBG;
    private Bitmap mIcon2;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        layoutBG = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.li2);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cursor.getPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cursor.getPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.LL = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.layoutBG);
            holder.rowID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rawId);
            holder.info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Info);
            holder.dateDisp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.dateDisp);
            holder.day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            holder.finish = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.finish);
            holder.hourMin = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.hourMin);
            holder.shiftDisp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.shiftDisp);
            holder.start = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start);
            holder.timestarted = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.timestarted);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Code for holder class:

```
    static class ViewHolder {

    TextView rowID;
    TextView info;
    TextView dateDisp;
    TextView day;
    TextView timestarted;
    TextView start;
    TextView finish;
    TextView hourMin;
    TextView shiftDisp;
    LinearLayout LL;

}
```

Comment: There are multiple examples here on SO. I suggest you take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4141385/1029225).